# AngularJS Force submit dont send some hidden input values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with an angular app. Everything goes fine, the final PHP catches all the values from the inputs except the **'prods'** field wich is empty

HTML Code

```
<form name="goToPaymentForm" id="goToPaymentForm" ng-form-commit action="payment.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" id="payment_method" name="payment_method" ng-value="payment" />
      <input type="hidden" id="prods" name="prods" ng-value="prods" />
      <input type="hidden" id="terms" name="terms" ng-value="legalTermsAccepted" />
    </form>
```

Angular Code

```
app.directive("ngFormCommit", [function(){
    return {
        require:"form",
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr, $form) {
            $form.commit = function() {
                $el[0].submit();
            };
        }
    };
}]);

$scope.goToPayment = function($form){
    $scope.prods = JSON.stringify($scope.cart);
    $form.commit();
}
```

In console I catch this text:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

Why I dont use AJAX for sending? I submit the form because I have a controller which will redirect the browser to the proper secure payment platform (the user cannot interact with this, despite of javascript redirection methods). Why I am doing wrong? Why my prods hidden field has an empty value?

Final PHP Result

```
{
    payment_method: "paypal",
    prods: "",
    terms: "true"
}
```

Comment: If i do  `console.log($scope.prods);` just before the commit() function the value is set perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should bind the prods with the ng-model directive so that you can get it's value in AngularJS. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="prods" id="prods" name="prods" ng-value="prods" />
```

And here's the documentation about this directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Same result, but thanks for your response. Maybe it can be the length of the value or some character?

Comment: Well, the problem is actually because you're sending JSON through standard form submit. Try adding this attribute to your form tag, like this : <form enctype='application/json'> . Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/

Comment: Then why if I use out of angular code from jQuery like `$('#prods').val(JSON.stringify($scope.cart))`it works????